# Passing class with pointer to array from C++ to CUDA

Tags: c++, performance, cuda

I have the following class in C++:

```
template<typename T>
class dynArray {

 public:
    T *elements;
    int size;
    int capacity;
    int initCapacity;
}
```

Is there any way to copy an object of this class to use in a CUDA kernel using `cudaMemcpy()` without having to copy its content element by element?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### First thoughts

To me it seems that you want to have something like `std::vector<>` on the GPU. I would give the advice to really think about, if you only need the data in the GPU global memory or also the size of the vector. IMHO, the code on the GPU should really only modify the data of the array but do not resize the array itself. This is something that should be done on the host.

There is an open-source library called [AGILE](https://lamp2.tugraz.at/%7Eimt/joomla15/index.php/research/agile-gpu-image-reconstruction-library), which implements a `GPUVector` which is basically something like `std::vector<>` on the GPU. The `GPUVector` stores the capacity, the size and a pointer to the GPU memory. A kernel which operates on a `GPUVector` gets the pointer to the memory area and the size as arguments, i.e. the kernel calls look something like this:

```
GPUVector v;
[... initialize v...]
computationKernel<<<blockDim, gridDim>>>(v.data(), v.size());
```

Translating this to your class, `GPUVector::data()` would just return `dynArray::elements` (which points to **GPU memory**) and `GPUVector::size()` returns `dynArray::size`. The `dynArray::size` should stay on the CPU side because you most likely do not want to modify it from GPU code (for example because you cannot call `cudaMalloc` from the GPU). If you don't modify it, you can as well pass it as a parameter.

Another libray you might want to look at is [Thrust](http://thrust.github.com/), which also provides an STL-like vector on the GPU.

### A copy method for dynArray

As it is still desired to copy the whole array, I would suggest the following approach:

```
template<typename T>
class dynArray 
{
  public:
    //! Copies this dynArray to the GPU and returns a pointer to the copy.
    void* copyToDevice()
    {
        // Copy the dynArray to the device.
        void* deviceArray;
        cudaMalloc(&deviceArray, sizeof(dynArray<T>));
        cudaMemcpy(deviceArray, this, sizeof(dynArray<T>), 
                   cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    
        // Copy the elements array to the device.
        void* deviceElements;
        cudaMalloc(&deviceElements, sizeof(T) * capacity);
        cudaMemcpy(deviceElements, elements, sizeof(T) * capacity, 
                   cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    
        // On the device, the elements pointer has to point to deviceElements.
        cudaMemcpy(deviceArray, deviceElements, sizeof(T*),
                   cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

        return deviceArray;
    }
    
    T *elements;
    int size;
    int capacity;
    int initCapacity;
}
```

Comment: I've looked at Thrust, but I did not know AGILE. My problem is that the code I want to pass to CUDA includes the creation of a vector to which elements are added, the objective of the above structure was to avoid the use of vectors...

Comment: @dx_mrt: So you mean, you will dynamically change the size of dynArray in the code executed on the GPU? I expect that you will run into problems, if `size` grows above `capacity`. Of course, you could create an array large enough for all cases but this could be a waste of _quite precious_ GPU memory.

Comment: Ok, looks like it's possible to do free() and malloc() inside the kernel if one uses something like this: `cudaDeviceSetLimit (cudaLimitMallocHeapSize, 128*1024*1024)`

Comment: @dx_mrt: That's great! Up to now I was not aware that you could now also call `malloc()` and `free()` from device functions. For [reference](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5249450/1450656).

Answer (score 0):

I think the pointer `element` will be a problem, since you will have to copy the contents of your `elements` array separately and then the pointer will be messed up (i.e. it will not point to the `element` array on the GPU). I would recommend to copy the element array and the size/capactiy values separately.