# Does gpuocelot support dynamic memory allocation in CUDA device?

Tags: cuda, nvidia, dynamic-memory-allocation, gpu

My algorithm (parallel multi-frontal Gaussian elimination) needs to dynamically allocate memory (tree building) inside CUDA kernel. Does anyone know if gpuocelot supports such things?

According to this: [stackoverflow-link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715238/cuda-allocate-memory-in-device-function) and CUDA programming guide I can do such things. But with gpuocelot I get errors during runtime.

**Errors:**

1. When I call `malloc()` inside kernel I get this error:

   ```
   (2.000239) ExternalFunctionSet.cpp:371:  Assertion message: LLVM required to call external host functions from PTX.
   solver: ocelot/ir/implementation/ExternalFunctionSet.cpp:371: void ir::ExternalFunctionSet::ExternalFunction::call(void*, const ir::PTXKernel::Prototype&): Assertion false' failed.
   ```
2. When I try to get or set malloc heap size (inside host code):

   ```
   solver: ocelot/cuda/implementation/CudaRuntimeInterface.cpp:811: virtual cudaError_t cuda::CudaRuntimeInterface::cudaDeviceGetLimit(size_t*, cudaLimit): Assertion `0 && "unimplemented"' failed.
   ```

Maybe I have to point (somehow) to compiler that I want to use device `malloc()`?

Any advice?

Comment: I am reasonably sure the emulator has baked in `malloc`, `free` and `printf` support, but I am not so certain about the LLVM backend. You should really ask this on the Ocelot mailing list. It isn't really a CUDA question at all and I am tempted to remove the CUDA tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the answer in gpu ocelot mailing list:

[gpuocelot mailing list link](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/gpuocelot/XU-LcwXdHG8/discussion)