# couldn't allocate an array of size 2116800 on device code

Tags: c++, memory, cuda, gpu, nvcc

I have a class `Color` with 3 `double` variable and another class `Image` with an array of `Color`. The problem is I can't allocate a `Color` array of size `1960*1080` on GPU code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

// limited version of checkCudaErrors from helper_cuda.h in CUDA examples
#define checkCudaErrors(val) check_cuda((val), #val, __FILE__, __LINE__)

void check_cuda(cudaError_t result, char const* const func, const char* const file,
                int const line) {
    if (result) {
        std::cerr << "CUDA error = " << static_cast<unsigned int>(result) << " at " << file << ":"
                << line << " '" << func << "' \n";
        // Make sure we call CUDA Device Reset before exiting
        cudaDeviceReset();
        exit(-1);
    }
}

class Color {
public:
    double r, g, b;

    __host__ __device__ Color() : r(0.0), g(0.0), b(0.0) {
    }
};

class Image {
public:
    int width = -1;
    int height = -1;

    Color* frame_buffer = nullptr;

    __device__ Image(int _width, int _height) : width(_width), height(_height) {
        frame_buffer = new Color[width * height];
    }

    __device__ ~Image() {
        delete frame_buffer;
    }
};

__global__ void init_gpu_image(Image* image, int width,
                               int height) {
    printf("block id:  (%d, %d, %d)\n", blockIdx.x, blockIdx.y, blockIdx.z);
    printf("thread id: (%d, %d, %d)\n", threadIdx.x, threadIdx.y, threadIdx.z);
    *image = Image(width, height);
}

int main() {
    int width = 1960;
    int height = 1080;

    printf("image dimension: %d\n", width * height);
    printf("image size: %d\n", sizeof(Color) * width * height);

    /*
    // works fine when allocating with cudaMallocManaged()
    Color* frame_buffer;
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMallocManaged((void **)&frame_buffer, sizeof(Color) * width * height));
    checkCudaErrors(cudaGetLastError());
    checkCudaErrors(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
    */

    Image* gpu_image;
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMallocManaged((void **)&gpu_image, sizeof(Image)));
    init_gpu_image<<<1, 1>>>(gpu_image, width, height);

    checkCudaErrors(cudaGetLastError());
    checkCudaErrors(cudaDeviceSynchronize());

    return 0;
}
```

full output:

```
image dimension: 2116800
image size: 50803200
block id:  (0, 0, 0)
thread id: (0, 0, 0)
CUDA error = 700 at /home/wentao/Desktop/cuda-test/main.cu:68 'cudaDeviceSynchronize()'
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18 FATAL_ERROR)

if (NOT CMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER)
    set(CMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER "/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc")
    # required by CLion
endif ()

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

project(cuda_test LANGUAGES CUDA CXX)

add_executable(cuda_test main.cu)

target_compile_options(cuda_test PRIVATE $<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:CUDA>:
        --expt-relaxed-constexpr
        >)
```

Comment: [Segmentation fault on large array sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1847789/segmentation-fault-on-large-array-sizes)

Comment: @user12002570 So I could only allocate it with malloc on GPU?

Comment: How do you want it to work?  Allocate on PC and transfer to GPU or allocate in GPU and use within GPU.  Do you need to keep a copy on the PC?  Are you going to do any manipulations on the PC and then transfer back to GPU or is everything done on the GPU?

Comment: @cup I hope to allocate it in GPU and use and modify within GPU and finally transfer back to CPU. (I don't need a copy on CPU before that)

Comment: GPU memory is separate from host (CPU) memory. You should allocate memory on the GPU with e.g. `cudaMalloc`, then copy it to/from host memoy with `cudaMemcpy` family.

Comment: @wohlstad So there is no way to allocate GPU memory dynamically from device code?

Comment: @Rahn I now see that there is actually a way - using `malloc` - see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715238/cuda-allocate-memory-in-device-function.

Comment: This (dynamic allocations by GPU threads) isn't how it's typically done. Normally, the `Image` object would be a normal C++ object in CPU memory that manages the GPU-side array allocation of `frame_buffer`. Width and height would be passed to the GPU as kernel parameters. Don't overcomplicate the GPU-side with complex objects, especially as a beginner. That's not what the GPU is good at.

Comment: Do you have a good reason to use double-precision here? This seems a huge waste of resources. Generally, each component fits in 8 bits. Some platforms use 10-bit integers but I never seen any project requiring 64-bit double-precision components (6x-8x times more). Simple-precision is already generally more than enough. Be aware that double-precision is generally slower and mainstream PC GPU are not suited for double-precision computing so they are likely to be slower than the CPU of the target PC (assuming the code is optimized).

Comment: By the way, using an array of `Color` is neither efficient on GPU nor on CPU. You should use an array of small native type (e.g. `uint8_t`, `int16_t` or `float`) per component (so 3 arrays) for the computation to be more efficiently in general (more SIMD friendly and better memory alignment).

Comment: … and if you keep the components interlaced, consider switching to 4 components (RGBA). Even if you don't use the fourth channel, a vector of 4 is more efficient since its size is a power of 2. CUDA comes with [builtin vector types](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#built-in-vector-types) for this

Answer (score 4):

CUDA C++ `new` and `delete` operators in device code rely on device-side `malloc` (see [this section of the CUDA C++ Programming Guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#dynamic-global-memory-allocation-and-operations) for more information), which most likely fails here given that it is not designed to handle large allocations like the 50MB you are trying to allocate.

In order to address the issue, you can manually extend the heap using:

```cpp
cudaDeviceSetLimit(cudaLimitMallocHeapSize, sizeof(Color) * width * height + (1 << 24));
```

which is the size of the image, plus 16MiB to account for allocator metadata and alignment.

**I recommend against allocating such a large allocation on the device heap** given that it is not possible to resize it once it has been used, therefore alocating memory you cannot reclaim. Instead, I would recommend looking into `cudaMallocAsync` for allocating memory in the most efficient way. See [this section of the CUDA runtime API documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY__POOLS.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY__POOLS) for more information on the stream-ordered memory allocation APIs.

For future reference, you can use [NVIDIA's compute-sanitizer](https://docs.nvidia.com/compute-sanitizer/) to debug these types of issues. compute-sanitizer clearly highlights the allocation failure (`malloc(...)` returns `nullptr`):

```
$ compute-sanitizer --show-backtrace device ./test
========= COMPUTE-SANITIZER
image dimension: 2116800
image size: 50803200
block id:  (0, 0, 0)
thread id: (0, 0, 0)
========= Invalid __global__ write of size 8 bytes
=========     at Image::Image(int, int)+0x3b0 in /tmp/tmp.QmgDY96jb8/test.cu:33
=========     by thread (0,0,0) in block (0,0,0)
=========     Address 0x0 is out of bounds
=========     and is 8,675,917,824 bytes before the nearest allocation at 0x205200000 of size 8,388,864 bytes
=========     Device Frame:init_gpu_image(Image *, int, int)+0x290 in /tmp/tmp.QmgDY96jb8/test.cu:45
=========
========= Program hit cudaErrorLaunchFailure (error 719) due to "unspecified launch failure" on CUDA API call to cudaDeviceSynchronize.
=========
CUDA error = 719 at test.cu:68 'cudaDeviceSynchronize()'
========= Target application returned an error
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors
```

Comment: Could you explain a bit `(sizeof(Color) + sizeof(double)) * width * height`? I don't understand why `sizeof(double)` is needed here.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, the `sizeof(double)` has no specific meaning and was just used to increase the heap size. I removed it and replaced it with a generic 16MiB add to account for internal metadata and alignment. The device-side allocator internals are not public, and this is subject to change in the future.

As mentioned on the answer, **I do recommend against using this approach**. My goal here was to demonstrate that it was a heap size issue, and I achieved that by increasing the heap size. Hope that helps!

Comment: I'm sorry, regarding "allocating such a large allocation on the device heap" and "allocating memory you cannot reclaim", couldn't you just invoke `delete ptr` in device code to free device heap space?

Comment: In that specific case the failure happens when `new Color[...]` is called. It is never created, since you do not have enough space to allocate your array on the device heap.